# wants to mark the currently use file in my ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

i build application who take all the files in my ListView (pcap files )and start to play all the packets.
what i want is that the currently file that play will mark and after this file finish the next file after will be marked and the focus will be all the time on the selected file (i dont want to manually acroll to see the file)
what i have now is that the first file marked and after it finish my application markes also the second and after the third together.

tis is my start button:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {                        
                lvFiles.EnsureVisible(i);
                lvFiles.Items[i].Selected = true;
                filePath = lvFiles.Items[i].Tag.ToString();
            });

            PcapFile pcapFile = new PcapFile();
            pcapFile.sendQueue(filePath, adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

`lvFiles` is my ListView, `PcapFile` is my class and `pcapFile.sendQueue` is the method who start the play.

Comment: Have you tried to set lvFiles.SelectedIndex = i; ?

Comment: there is not SelectedIndex in ListView (ListBox does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Select()` on the listview for this. Also don't forget to unselect current item before selecting next one.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {                        
            lvFiles.EnsureVisible(i);
            lvFiles.Items[i].Selected = true;
            lvFiles.Select();
            filePath = lvFiles.Items[i].Tag.ToString();
        });

        PcapFile pcapFile = new PcapFile();
        pcapFile.sendQueue(filePath, adapter);
        lvFiles.Items[i].Selected = false;
    }
```

Comment: what about EnsureVisible and Selected (the others 2 properties that i am using in my example) ? FocusedItem  alone and with my properties did not set the focus on the file in use